# For loop finding more files than it should

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I have the following for loop in a small shell script I wrote.

```
    for file in /home/place/incoming/MYSQLIST_*.zip
do
    name=`echo $file|awk -F "MYSQLIST_" {'print$2'}` #get type
    name=`echo $name|awk -F ".zip" {'print$1'}` #remove extension

    unzip -Co ${file} -d /home/place/incoming/

    name=`echo type_${name}` 
    echo $name >> collect.txt
    directory=`echo /home/place/incoming/${name}.csv` 
    echo $directory >> collect.txt

    #cleanup
    rm ${name}.csv
    rm phpvars.txt
    mv ${file} ${file}.DONE  
done
echo Done
```

This script works as intended most of the time.  I have files that arrive to this directory that come in the format of MYSQLIST_####.zip and also MYSQL_########.zip  As what we would expect, this script should ignore the files named MYSQL_########.zip.  What I have noticed is this for loop has been extracting the whole name MYSQL_########.zip and writing it to collect.txt.

Normally my collect.txt would have the following in it:

type_21345

/home/place/incoming/type_12345.csv

however in  few cases, this is what was found in the collect.txt:

MYSQL_12345678

/home/place/incoming/MYSQL_12345678.csv

Is it possible that I am missing a catch before my for loop or I should have one within my loop to check if the name of the file is really what it should be (MYSQLIST_*.ZIP)?

I am not looking for a answer like  "give me code", I would like to know if anyone else has seen something similar(misbehaving for loops) or guidance in error checking.

Comment: `name=$(echo type_${name})` is more efficiently written `name=type_${name}`.

Comment: I would also recommend `name=${file##*MYSQLIST_}` and `name=${name%.zip}` instead of using `awk` to process the file names.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to place quotations around your variables in case there are spaces or metacharacters in the filenames. i.e.

```
name=`echo $name ....`
```

should be

```
name=`echo "$name" ....`
```

etc.